# How do I log user out on macos 10.15

Tags: macos, administrator

Per this: https://osxdaily.com/2015/08/17/log-out-other-user-without-logging-in-mac-os-x/
all users should be listed in activity monitor[image]

but I only see the process for my user.
So how do I boot other users out, or have his processes listed?

Comment: As explained in the page you link to you need to switch to "All processes" to see `loginwindow` processes of other users.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was right there in comments under the article

```
users
id {usernametobootout}
sudo launchctl bootout user/{useridtobootout}
```